# Is there a function in Archer that could draw a line separating two outputs in a single field?

Tags: archer

I am trying to concatenate 2 outputs in calculated text field. But I would like to draw a line in between them or at least give them a heading, so that the users will be able to identify them easily. I could make different fields and have them calculated. But the requirement is to concatenate 15 fields into one field. So, I do not want to create 15 fields and write separate calcs. See below example

Example 1)

### Hello, this is an example of what I am trying to explain with an example (o/p 1)

Hello, this is how I would like to present to the end users avoiding confusion (o/p 2)

As you see above, I was able to concatenate 2 o/p's, but I would like to draw a line. This one scenario that would work for me.

Example 2)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ViBf.png)

Users Watch
Hello, this is an example of what I am trying to explain with an example (o/p 1)
Admin Watch
Hello, this is how I would like to present to the end users avoiding confusion (o/p 2)

As you see in 2nd example, I would like to put a heading for o/p 1 as "users watch" and "Admin Watch" for o/p 2, so that the users can differentiate it.

I have tried sub-string function for example 2, it looks 'OK' but it would be of more help if anyone has better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The beauty of Archer is that you can use HTML in the calculation; providing that the calculated field is a text field and that its display is set as text area.

You can use the following calculation:

```
CONCATENATE("<H3>Header 1</H3>", [Field 1], "<H3>Header 2</H3>", [Field 2])
```

Comment: Thank you @DjP, it is working absolutely fine...Is there function, where we draw a line? Is it possible in Archer with HTML or any other functions? I have been looking at most of the functions, but none of them has that functionality. TIA

Comment: Glad it's working for you.  Use the <hr> (horizontal rule) element.  Or do <h3 style='border-bottom: 1px solid black'>

Comment: Thank you DjP. Can we make a button and display the information when a end user clicks it? I am able to print a button, but I couldn't embed the data into it? Is Archer that feasible? The syntax I am using to print a button in Archer is:             "<font size="3"><i><BUTTON><B><H> Security Comments </H> </BUTTON>", I tried HTML Java script too, but I getting errors and Archer does say the errors but it doesn't show where the error is...

Comment: At this point, I'd start a new post on this being it differs from your initial ask.  But to answer your question.  You'll need to use a Custom (layout) Object and use HTML/JavaScript to build the button and display text to the user.